# Adding extra HTML tags and attributes to Django crispy-forms fields

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm using django-crispy-forms with Bootstrap and I'm wanting to add some extra HTML **inside** the HTML rendered for the a single field.

For example if my form contains,

```
recipients = forms.CharField(label='To',widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter phone number, contact or group (add as many as you like)'}))
```

Then the normal rendering (using the Bootstrap templates) is,

```
<div id="div_id_recipients" class="control-group">
    <label for="id_recipients" class="control-label requiredField">
         To<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
         <input class="textinput textInput" id="id_recipients" name="recipients" placeholder="Enter phone number, contact or group (add as many as you like)" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is have some extra HTML appear just before the final closing div. So it would look like,

```
<div id="div_id_recipients" class="control-group">
    <label for="id_recipients" class="control-label requiredField">
         To<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
         <input class="textinput textInput" id="id_recipients" name="recipients" placeholder="Enter phone number, contact or group (add as many as you like)" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="controls-aside">
         <button type="button" class="btn">Address Book</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn">Add Contact</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

I know that I can replace the existing template for this field with a custom template but I want to be able to re-use their template without doing a copy/paste since that makes it not very maintainable.

So what is the best way to implement this? I also want to add an extra class to the **label** if anyone can suggest how to do it?

Comment: Crispy forms allow you to override your forms layout and add also elements, have you read the documentation?:
http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html

Comment: I've been through the docs pretty exhaustively several times. The layout overrides don't allow me to add content **inside** the control group where I need it unless I write custom templates for them. But then there is an issue with maintainability because I have to keep my templates in line with the standard ones. I guess the main option I have currently is see if the designer can change the templates so that the content can be moved to outside the control group instead.

Comment: If you read more carefully, you can create the form layout inside a forms.py file by using the available tags, especially something like `Button('address_book', 'Address Book')`

Comment: @petkostas Yes, I'm well aware of that option. However, as I said previously, that option does not allow me to add HTML **inside** a Bootstrap `control-group`. All it will do is **append** a new `control-group` on the end of the previous `control-group`. This is a trivial solution and I would not have needed to ask anything on SO if the design allowed for that.

Comment: Sorry my bad, hadn't seen the control group, in that case, yes you will need a custom template to override that behavior, unless your design allows you to group the elements in another wrapper class, in which case you can use the wrapper class of crispy forms.

Answer (score 2):

1. For completeness, but not for your case: even after layout creation, [`Layout.wrap('recipients', Div)`](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamic_layouts.html#wrap) will work if one only needs to wrap a control into an additional `Div`.
2. About adding HTML inside the layout. Last hour I needed a very custom HTML, so did this:

(formatting)

```
i = self.helper.layout.fields.index('guest_email')
self.helper.layout.insert(
    i+1,
    HTML('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(
        reverse_lazy('invite_guests'),
        _('Invite to a party'))
))
```

I came here googling for a HTMLWrapper class example for Crispy Forms, so that I could do a prettier thing instead:

```
self.helper['guest_email'].wrap(HTMLWrapper(
    'guest_email', 
     before='',
     after='<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(href, title))
```

If I end up creating one, I'll get back and post it.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked that way:

```
from crispy_forms.layout import Field, HTML

self.helper["some_field_name"].wrap(Field, HTML("<p>Example</p>"))
```

The benefit of using HTML is that it also gives you the possibility to use context variables.